# Kernel panic while dereferencing memory mapped by phys_to_virt() in Android

Tags: android, c, linux-device-driver

I have reserved 1MB memory by passing kernel command args (By modifying BoardConfig.mk, memmap = 1MB$0xXYZ). I mapped same reserved memory in to virtual address using phys_to_virt() from Kernel space. However, when i try to write some value on the virtual address or try to read from virtual address, i receive Kernel Panic.

```
[  130.771566] BUG: unable to handle kernel [  130.773209] type=1400 audit(1420071245.646:367): avc: denied { read } for pid=2536 comm=47465844204D6F6E69746F72 scontext=u:r:gfxd:s0 tcontext=u:r:gfxd:s0 tclass=netlink_kobject_uevent_socket permissive=1

[  130.796171] paging request at ffff880050400000
[  130.801361] IP: [<ffffffffa008905f>] chardev_init+0x5f/0x1000 [reserve_memory_test]
[  130.809945] PGD 2455067 PUD 2458067 PMD 2459067 PTE 0
[  130.815685] Oops: 0002 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[  130.820136] Modules linked in: reserve_memory_test(O+) ip6table_raw iptable_raw lib2600_mod_bxtB0 lib2600psys_mod_bxtB0 snd_soc_bxt_gpmrb snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_sst_acpi snd_soc_sst_match snd_hda_ext_core snd_hda_core hci_uart btbcm bluetooth rfkill_gpio igb_avb(O) cfg80211 intel_ipu4_isys_mod_bxtB0 intel_ipu4_psys_mod_bxtB0 intel_ipu4_mmu_bxtB0 intel_ipu4_mod_bxtB0 intel_ipu4_wrapper_bxtB0 intel_ipu4_acpi videobuf2_dma_contig as3638 dw9714 lm3643 crlmodule smiapp smiapp_pll
[  130.872031] CPU: 0 PID: 5870 Comm: insmod Tainted: G     U  W  O    4.4.19-quilt-2e5dc0ac-00331-gbf3bede #1
[  130.882926] task: ffff88014d404040 ti: ffff88015d7c8000 task.ti: ffff88015d7c8000
[  130.891305] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa008905f>]  [<ffffffffa008905f>] chardev_init+0x5f/0x1000 [reserve_memory_test]
[  130.902600] RSP: 0018:ffff88015d7cbcb8  EFLAGS: 00010246
[  130.908542] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffffff82013040 RCX: 0000000000000008
[  130.916521] RDX: 0000000080000000 RSI: ffff88015d7cbcb8 RDI: ffff880050400000
[  130.924490] RBP: ffff88015d7cbce0 R08: ffffc90000288000 R09: 0000000000000797
[  130.932469] R10: 0000000000001000 R11: 0000000000000797 R12: ffff88006ad47640
[  130.940448] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffffffa0089000 R15: ffff88015f1f49c0
[  130.948417] FS:  000077095dbc0bd8(0000) GS:ffff88017fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  130.957456] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  130.963873] CR2: ffff880050400000 CR3: 0000000154da1000 CR4: 00000000003406f0
[  130.971844] Last Branch Records:
[  130.975483]    to: [<ffffffff81963320>] page_fault+0x0/0x80
[  130.981737]  from: [<ffffffffa008905f>] chardev_init+0x5f/0x1000 [reserve_memory_test]
[  130.990607]    to: [<ffffffffa0089047>] chardev_init+0x47/0x1000 [reserve_memory_test]
[  130.999474]  from: [<ffffffff8117784d>] printk+0x4f/0x50
[  131.005430]    to: [<ffffffff81177846>] printk+0x48/0x50
[  131.011382]  from: [<ffffffff810e4be0>] vprintk_default+0x20/0x30
[  131.018213]    to: [<ffffffff810e4bdf>] vprintk_default+0x1f/0x30
[  131.025042]  from: [<ffffffff810e46cf>] vprintk_emit+0x16f/0x530
[  131.031763]    to: [<ffffffff810e46c1>] vprintk_emit+0x161/0x530
[  131.038497]  from: [<ffffffff810e47c7>] vprintk_emit+0x267/0x530
[  131.045218]    to: [<ffffffff810e47bb>] vprintk_emit+0x25b/0x530
[  131.051949]  from: [<ffffffff810bc345>] preempt_count_sub+0x35/0xb0
[  131.058972]    to: [<ffffffff810bc33b>] preempt_count_sub+0x2b/0xb0
[  131.065991]  from: [<ffffffff810bc385>] preempt_count_sub+0x75/0xb0
[  131.073013]    to: [<ffffffff810bc37c>] preempt_count_sub+0x6c/0xb0
[  131.080032]  from: [<ffffffff810bc339>] preempt_count_sub+0x29/0xb0
[  131.087051]    to: [<ffffffff810bc310>] preempt_count_sub+0x0/0xb0
[  131.093970]  from: [<ffffffff810e47b6>] vprintk_emit+0x256/0x530
[  131.100682]    to: [<ffffffff810e47b1>] vprintk_emit+0x251/0x530
[  131.107412]  from: [<ffffffff810e4842>] vprintk_emit+0x2e2/0x530
[  131.114142]    to: [<ffffffff810e4842>] vprintk_emit+0x2e2/0x530
[  131.120895]  from: [<ffffffff810e4307>] console_unlock+0x2a7/0x500
[  131.127821]    to: [<ffffffff810e42f9>] console_unlock+0x299/0x500
[  131.134747]  from: [<ffffffff810e404e>] wake_up_klogd+0x5e/0x70
[  131.141381]    to: [<ffffffff810e4041>] wake_up_klogd+0x51/0x70
[  131.148014]  from: [<ffffffff810bc345>] preempt_count_sub+0x35/0xb0
[  131.155026]    to: [<ffffffff810bc33b>] preempt_count_sub+0x2b/0xb0
[  131.162042]  from: [<ffffffff810bc385>] preempt_count_sub+0x75/0xb0
[  131.169062]    to: [<ffffffff810bc37c>] preempt_count_sub+0x6c/0xb0
[  131.176082]  from: [<ffffffff810bc339>] preempt_count_sub+0x29/0xb0
[  131.183136]    to: [<ffffffff810bc310>] preempt_count_sub+0x0/0xb0
[  131.190061]  from: [<ffffffff810e403c>] wake_up_klogd+0x4c/0x70
```

At the same time, when i try to access same physical memory from user space using mmap("/dev/mem",.....) and try to read and write, i don't get any error and receive expected value.

Comment: I think you can use one of the `ioremap_` functions such as `ioremap_nocache` to map the desired region of reserved physical memory to a kernel virtual address. Ideally, you should also request the memory region first using `request_mem_region`.

Comment: *"I mapped same reserved memory in to virtual address using phys_to_virt() from Kernel space."* -- **phys_to_virt()** is a translation routine, and does not perform a new mapping.  The translation requires a mapping to exist.

Comment: @Ian: I tried ioremap_nocache() to map reserved physical memory to kernel virtual address. It worked fine and output was expected.

However, Why was problem observed with phys_to_virt()?